# Celery doesn't restart subprocesses

Tags: celery, supervisord

I have an issue with celery deployment - when I restart it old subprocesses don't stop and continue to process some of jobs. I use supervisord to run celery. Here is my config:

```
$ cat /etc/supervisor/conf.d/celery.conf 
[program:celery]
; Full path to use virtualenv, honcho to load .env
command=/home/ubuntu/venv/bin/honcho run celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color

directory=/home/ubuntu/app
environment=PATH="/home/ubuntu/venv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
user=ubuntu
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celery.log
stderr_logfile=/home/ubuntu/logs/celery.err
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10

; Need to wait for currently executing tasks to finish at shutdown.
; Increase this if you have very long running tasks.
stopwaitsecs = 600

; When resorting to send SIGKILL to the program to terminate it
; send SIGKILL to its whole process group instead,
; taking care of its children as well.
killasgroup=true

; if rabbitmq is supervised, set its priority higher
; so it starts first
priority=998
```

Here is how celery processes look:

```
$ ps axwu | grep celery
ubuntu     983  0.0  0.1  47692 10064 ?        S    11:47   0:00 /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/honcho run celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
ubuntu     984  0.0  0.0   4440   652 ?        S    11:47   0:00 /bin/sh -c celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
ubuntu     985  0.0  0.5 168720 41356 ?        S    11:47   0:01 /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
ubuntu     990  0.0  0.4 167936 36648 ?        S    11:47   0:00 /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
ubuntu     991  0.0  0.4 167936 36648 ?        S    11:47   0:00 /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/python /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
```

When I run `sudo supervisorctl restart celery` it only stops first process `python ... honcho` one and all the other ones continue. And if I try to kill them they continue (`kill -9` works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be [a bug with honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho/issues/1). I ended up with workaround of starting this script from supervisor:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/activate
exec env $(cat .env | grep -v ^# | xargs) \
     celery -A stargeo worker -l info --no-color
```